# calling a service angular2 error 'Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to call service from my login.ts but i keep getting different errors. here is my code

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, User } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {
    authType: string = "login";
    error: string;
    storage: Storage = new Storage();

  constructor(public auth: Auth, public user: User, public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: AuthService) {}

  facebookLogin() {
    this.auth.login('facebook').then((success) => {
        this.authService.signup(this.user.social.facebook).then((success) => {

        });
    });

  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { AuthHttp, JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  // contentHeader = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  storage: Storage = new Storage();
  refreshSubscription: any;
  user: Object;
  zoneImpl: NgZone;
  idToken: string;
  error: string;

  constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp, zone: NgZone) {
    this.zoneImpl = zone;
    // Check if there is a profile saved in local storage
    this.storage.get('profile').then(profile => {
      this.user = JSON.parse(profile);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    this.storage.get('id_token').then(token => {
      this.idToken = token;
    });
  }

  public authenticated() {
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token', this.idToken);
  }

  public signup(params) {
    var url = 'http://127:0.0.1:3000/api/v1/register';
    return this.authHttp.post(url, JSON.stringify(params))
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {this.storage.set('id_token', data.token)},
          err => this.error = err
        );
  }
}
```

SO basically what i want is when the `facebookLogin()` is clicked, it goes to `auth.service.ts` and gets the `singup()` method which returns the value.

But i keep getting a `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.`

What does this mean and how do i resolve this?

Comment: Seems to me that your auth.login is returning an observable not a promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change subscribe to `toPromise()` (don't forget to import `toPromise`)

```
  public signup(params) {
    var url = 'http://127:0.0.1:3000/api/v1/register';
    return this.authHttp.post(url, JSON.stringify(params))
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise(
          data => {this.storage.set('id_token', data.token)},
        );
  }
```

or to `.map()` and then use `subscribe()` instead of `then()` on the call site.

```
 public signup(params) {
    var url = 'http://127:0.0.1:3000/api/v1/register';
    return this.authHttp.post(url, JSON.stringify(params))
        .map(res => {
          let data = res.json();
          this.storage.set('id_token', data.token);
          return data;
        });
  }
```

```
  facebookLogin() {
    this.auth.login('facebook').then((success) => {
        this.authService.signup(this.user.social.facebook).subscribe((success) => {

        });
    });

  }
```

Comment: ur solution works but can i know why mine was wrong? still trying to grasp angular2.

Comment: `.then()` is available on a `Promise` but `signup` returns an `Observable`. `toPromise` creates a `Promise` from an `Observable` which makes `then()` work, or (my 2nd approach) you just stick with `Observable` and use operators that work on observables like `subscribe()` and `map()`.

Comment: I had some errors in my code (first example I removed the `error ...` line inside `toPromise(...)` and in the 2nd example I added `return data;` in `map(...)` otherwise the subscriber probably doesn't receive any data (or rather what  `this.storage.set(...)` returns.